# {SQL PHP} Help by building query

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Maybe a stupid question, but i am in a bit of a rush.
I am asked to change some php files, which is done, but i am stuck on the query needed to make it fully work.

I have the next 2 tables named: Orders and Customers

I use the following query to display all information from the orders table:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE ORD_ID="$ID";
```

This displays something like this:

```
Order number = 1
object = Testobject
Customer = 256
```

now i want customer to display with their name, like Dutch Developer instead of 256

The table Customer looks like this:

ID
Name

So The Customer number in the table orders should be linked to the id in Customer and then the ID in customer should be linked to the Name. And then it should display only the name.

Maybe it is a very easy thing, but my sql knowledge is not that good.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a correlated query:

```
SELECT o.* ,
       (SELECT c.customer_name FROM customers c
        WHERE c.id = o.customer) as cust_name 
FROM orders o
```

This is for all orders, if you want it for a specific one then add the `WHERE` clause back

```
WHERE ORD_ID="$ID";
```

Comment: Thanks, any reason why you did t.* instead of *?

Comment: I meant `o.*` , but no, both will result the same in this case. Just looks better and easier to understand what exactly this query does. @Dutchdeveloper

Answer (score 2):

Try a JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
JOIN Customers ON Customers.ID = Orders.Customer
WHERE ORD_ID="$ID";
```

The JOIN say's add this table WHERE Customer equals his Customers.ID

Comment: Thanks will try it

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`select b.name from Orders a,Customers b where a.number=b.id ;`